# Hide text input and button after click

Tags: r, shiny

I am new with Shiny. I have developed a very simple app that modifies a string inserted in a text input after the click of a button. The result appears in a text output present from the beginning. This is my code:

```
# ui.R

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  textInput("caption", "Caption", "abc"),
  actionButton("btn_input", "Enter"),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)

# server.R

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$value <- reactive({
        # toggle(id="caption")
        input$btn_input
        v <- isolate({input$caption})
        if (v == "xxx") {
            value <- paste(v, "a")
        } else {
            value <- paste(v, "b")
        }
        value
    })
}
```

I would like the text output to appear only after clicking the button.
At the same time I would like the caption, the text input and the button to disappear after clicking the button.

What is the easiest way to make this change? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `conditionalPanel` is the easiest way:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  conditionalPanel(
    "input.btn_input === 0",
    textInput("caption", "Caption", "abc"),
    actionButton("btn_input", "Enter")
  ),
  conditionalPanel(
    "input.btn_input !== 0",
    style = "display: none;",
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  Value <- eventReactive(input$btn_input, {
    v <- input$caption
    if (v == "xxx") {
      paste(v, "a")
    } else {
      paste(v, "b")
    }
  })
  
  output$value <- renderPrint({
    Value()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you want a "Back" button, as asked in your comment, you can proceed as follows:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  conditionalPanel(
    "output.show_input",
    textInput("caption", "Caption", "abc"),
    actionButton("btn_input", "Enter")
  ),
  conditionalPanel(
    "output.show_output",
    style = "display: none;",
    verbatimTextOutput("value"),
    actionButton("btn_back", "Back")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  ShowInput <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
  output$show_input <- reactive({
    ShowInput() 
  })
  outputOptions(output, "show_input", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

  ShowOutput <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  output$show_output <- reactive({
    ShowOutput() 
  })
  outputOptions(output, "show_output", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_input, {
    ShowInput(FALSE)
    ShowOutput(TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_back, {
    ShowInput(TRUE)
    ShowOutput(FALSE)
  })
  
  Value <- eventReactive(input$btn_input, {
    v <- input$caption
    if (v == "xxx") {
      paste(v, "a")
    } else {
      paste(v, "b")
    }
  })
  
  output$value <- renderPrint({
    Value()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It works, thanks. A curiosity: is there a way to implement the button "Back" when I'm on the result page or have I to restart the app?

Comment: @LJG Yes, see my answer, I've just edited it.

Comment: Interestingly, this button "complicates" the answer quite significantly. In any case everything works, thanks. I accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
# output$value <- reactive({
output$value <- eventReactive(input$btn_input, {
...
```

Comment: This shows the result only after the button is clicked, which is ok. But it doesn't hide the input text and the button.